# using tel: url to initiate call - but need to insert SPECIAL CHARACTER #

Tags: iphone, phone-call, tel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use tel: with * (star, asterisk) or # (hash, pound) on iOs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660951/how-to-use-tel-with-star-asterisk-or-hash-pound-on-ios)

I need to initiate a call which also enters an id separated by #

The problem is that as soon as I insert this special character the method does not fire (as explained in the doc, I know)

Also stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding does not change anything.

Is there a workaround? Can I send /simulate key strokes ?

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345#2"]];` <- because of the # it does not fire.

Thanks very much....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660951/40961

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible. And in another forum someone asked Apple about that, but never get an answer back

Answer (score 2):

CTCallDialWithID(@"12345#2", -1);

and link with CoreTelephony.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't fire neither, but thanks for the hint!

Comment: Oh yes, this works exactly as required - the only question now left is regarding appstore acceptance as I read in other places....and how would one know which solution is being used for the call...

Comment: Appstore will surely accept this.. check the app store for iCallREdialer app, it is implemented using core telephony only.

Comment: Do you mean "Auto Redial Helper" ? This is the only App I find when searching for "redial". By the way, this seems to return back to the app after the call has been made too!

Comment: Just got the confirmation that due to use of this function the app will not be accepted by the app store....need to find an alternative now!

Comment: FYI: Appstore rejected this solution, since it uses private API

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC2806](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt) you've got a 'post-dial' part that seemingly let's you do what you want.
Try:

```
tel:12345;postd=#2
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't fire as well, but thanks for the hint!